# Not taking three steps forward for the Chazzan's repetition

Tags: halacha, shemoneh-esrei, mistakes, chazzan-prayer-leader

Last Shabbat we had a guy fill in for Minchah as Chazzan. He did a great job. I'm sure he was just nervous and didn't want to err. But I noticed he didn't take the 3 steps forward for the repetition. (He finished the silent Amidah taking 3 steps back. But then started the repetition without taking a step forward. Not even for Kedushah.)

Was this no big deal or should it have been acknowledged and corrected?

Please explain if possible.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/10045/759